# Где скачать JRE 11

Tags: java, java-11

Скачал вчера свежую JDK 11 и поставил, но возникает ошибка.

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: hel has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Как я понял, это из-за того что JDK 11, и код скомпилирован на нём, а но моём компьютере версия джавы другая (восьмая), но вопрос в том, где я могу скачать JRE 11? Официальный сайт Оракла предлает только восьмую версию. Не бейте только за этот вопрос, я пытаюсь научиться, а вчера 11 Java вышла вот я её и скачал.

Comment: Вроде только 10 есть, или я отстал от жизни?

Comment: По-моему 11 вчера прямо и вышла,

Comment: https://habr.com/company/jugru/blog/424543/
Вышла :)

Comment: [Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать: Вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учеб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - поэтому давайте переформулируем вопрос без "где скачать".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

В Java 11 нет JRE. Если вы разработчик, вы можете запускать свою программу при помощи JDK 11. Если вы хотите делать это из командной строки, вы должны позаботиться о том, чтобы путь к `java` или к `java.exe` из JDK11 стоял, в переменной окружения `PATH`, раньше пути к `java` или к `java.exe` более старых JRE. При этом вы должны учесть, что в Windows установщики старых Public JRE копировали `java.exe` в директорию `C:\Windows\System32`, которая так же прописана в `PATH`. Лучше всего просто удалить старую Public JRE. Старый JDK удалять не обязательно, он не помешает.

Если же вы хотите послать свою программу конечному пользователю, у которого теперь нет подходящего JRE и который не хочет устанавливать JDK, вы должны создать рантайм среду (некое подобие старого JRE), которая будет включать лишь необходимые Java модули, включая модуль вашей программы.

Для примера разберём простой Hello world. Пусть ваша программа состоит из одного класса `com.example.MainClass` и является модулем `tryout`, то есть кроме `com/example/MainClass.java` у вас есть и `module-info.java` (в default пакете, то есть над `com`) с описанием модуля. Например с таким минимальным:

```
module tryout {
}
```

Кстати, в IntelliJ IDEA добавление модуля является отдельной операцией от добавления класса в меню `New`. Создать `module-info.java` тем же способом, которым вы создаёте обычный класс вы не сможете.

После сборки вашего проекта, например при помощи Maven, у вас получится некий jar файл, точное название которого совершенно неважно. Это jar файл и будет вашим модулем, описание которого будет у него внутри в `module-info.class`. Для создания рантайм среды вы должны запустить примерно такую комманду:

`jlink --module-path . --add-modules tryout --launcher start=tryout/com.example.MainClass --output tryoutapp`

Описание используемых параметров:

`--module-path .` говорит о том, где искать модули, кроме модулей JDK. В данном случае в текущей директории `.`.

`--add-modules tryout` говорит о том, какие модули включить, кроме модулей, включаемых по-умолчанию из JDK.

`--launcher start=tryout/com.example.MainClass` говорит о том, что нужно создать скрипты запуска `start` (UNIX Shell script) и `start.bat` (Batch script) которые будут запускать модуль `tryout`, запуская класс `com.example.MainClass` в этом модуле. Указание класса опционально и в моём случае понадобилось потому, что я поленился указать его в `MANIFEST.MF` внутри jar файла.

`--output tryoutapp` говорит о том, в какой директории создавать рантайм среду. При этом если такая директория уже существует и даже если она пустая, будет ошибка: "Error: directory already exists: tryoutapp".

В конечном итоге вы получите директорию `tryoutapp` внутри которой будет всё необходимое для запуска вашей программы (вашего модуля). При этом ваш jar файл вы там не найдёте. Ваш модуль (а значит и класс `com.example.MainClass`), вмести с остальными модулями, будет находиться в файле `tryoutapp/lib/modules`. В моём случае размер этого файла 23 мегабайта. Стартовые скрипты `start` и `start.bat` будут находиться в директории `tryoutapp/bin`.

Более детальное описание утилиты `jlink` вы можете получить запустив `jlink --help`.

Comment: это всё для новичка звучит очень страшно и непонятно, теперь даже не знаю что делать(

Comment: @Артём Новички могут ограничиться запуском своих программ при помощи JDK, то есть руководствоваться лишь первым абзацем.

Comment: ладно, вы очень помогли, буду пытаться)

Comment: Результат такой сборки будет платным ($5,000 за процессор?) для окончательного пользователя? Он же включает в себя часть JDK, который теперь бесплатен только для devtest и демонстрации, но не для production.

Comment: @PashaPash Зависит от JDK. Если OpenJDK, то бесплатным. Лицензия поменялась лишь в отношении Oracle JDK, а OpenJDK остался под GPL2+CE.

Comment: @РостиславКрасный Oracle JDK вроде бы тоже бесплатен по GPL (дотнетчик, могу ошибаться) - но вроде бы GPL (не LGPL) запрещает линковку и заставляет открывать исходники? OpenJDK можно использовать в энтерпрайз разработке, и не попадать под ограничения GPL "слинковался - показывай код"?

Comment: @РостиславКрасный ок, почитал, это решается припиской +CE )

Comment: @PashaPash Oracle JDK была бесплатной до выхода Java 11. Но теперь её лицензию BCL (а не GPL) изменили https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/oracle-jdk-releases-for-java-11-and-later OpenJDK имеет лицензию GPLv2 with Classpath Exception (GPL2+CE). Этот classpath exception и останавливает расползание GPL по слинкованому коду. Они не взяли LGPL, поскольку LGPL разрешает изучать и изменять слинкованый код. В остальном `GPL2+CE == LGPL2`

Answer (score 3):

jre 11 не будет. ссылка с картинки https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/oracle-jdk-releases-for-java-11-and-later

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ничего не понимаю( Как я могу запустить свой код на jdk11? Что мне нужно?

Comment: На сайте [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) можно скачать JRE 11 или любой другой версии.

Answer (score 0):

С сайта Eclipse Foundation можно скачать сборку JRE11 называемую "Eclipse Temurin by Adoptium" (ранее известную как AdoptOpenJDK)
https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=11
по ссылке выберите свою операционную систему (Linux, Windows или macOS) и архитектуру процессора (обычно x64)
Я, например, скачал версию `OpenJDK11U-jre_x64_windows_hotspot_11.0.18_10.msi`
[image: jdk-11.0.18+10 Temurin Released January 20, 2023 download JRE 42MB version]

```
JAVA -version
openjdk version "11.0.18" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.18+10 (build 11.0.18+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.18+10 (build 11.0.18+10, mixed mode)
```

Другим удобным способом скачать и установить одну или несколько версий среды выполнения JAVA является **SDKMAN!** - с его помощью можно переключаться между разными дистрибутивами Джавы
Изучите инструкцию по ссылке: https://sdkman.io/install

Также существуют варианты установки при помощи пакетного менеджера вашей операционной системы, например,

```
choco install temurin11jre
```

- для Windows, другой пакетный менеджер - https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli

macOS - https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/temurin

Linux - dnf или apt версии пакетов можно найти и сравнить/выбрать, например, здесь: https://pkgs.org/search/?q=jre

Answer (score -1):

[Ссылка на скачивание JDK 11 с сайта Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html)

Comment: Так вопрос в другом, я скачал, установил эту jdk, но скомпилированный код не выполняется ссылаясь на устаревший Java Runtime версии 52

Comment: Ну так и надо было об этом в вопросе написать))
Покажите вывод команды `java -version` в консоли

Comment: java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)