# A JNI error has occured, please check your installation and try again

Tags: java, javafx

При запуске .jar файла возникает следующая ошибка:

[image: Ошибка]

Использую JDK 12.0.1 и SDK JavaFX 12.0.1 версии, компилирую в IDE Intellij IDEA.
При тестах всё работает отлично, но когда скомпилирую даже не могу запустить.

Comment: Потому что запускаете с помощью Java 8.

Comment: Как тогда правильно запускать надо?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Где скачать JRE 11](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/886352/204271)

Comment: установите в систему jdk на которой разрабатываете, либо явно укахывайте путь до java

Comment: Теперь в консоли следующая проблема: javafx runtime components are missing and are required to run this application...